# Purple screen of death: can't get into ubuntu desktop or grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2

I bought a new laptop with ubuntu pre-installed on it. I have only had it for about a week and have already broke it! When I boot, only see a purple screen. When this first happened I restarted and was able to get into the grub menu by pressing shift. However, now that doesn't even work.

I honestly don't even know where do go from here. Does anyone have any next steps I could try or should I just try a reinstall?

**Edit:**

I was finally able to get grub up and was able to view the command line as it was booting. It looks like it gets hung up on "loading initial ramdisk."

Comment: I would never accept a pre-installed OS of any flavour... install yourself from scratch then you know what you're getting.

Comment: Did you do anything (install, update, delete, change) before you got the "purple" screen?  What version of Ubuntu came pre-installed?

Comment: Yes, I've updated/upgraded once since I got it, installed a few programs, ect. Most of which I did days ago and have used the laptop since. Yesterday I was having some issues with some partially installed packages (I think git?), but I just autoremoved them and was able to restart. The last thing I did before I shut my computer off was configure vim; added plugins, set come .vimrc stuff, ect. I am having this issue after bringing my laptop to work. But I am always vary careful when moving my laptop. Could this have something to do with not being on the home wifi?

Comment: @Thomas: Maybe someone did a really bad joke on you at the workplace. Do you recall anybody using your laptop? Maybe uninstalled some core program or package needed by Unity to run properly. My opinion: use a Live Ubuntu to rescue your personal data, then do a totally fresh install from scratch.

Comment: Thanks ipse. No, I was the first one in. I was wondering if it had something to do with Unity. I may just end up doing that. Thanks

Comment: If this helps anyone solve the actual problem, I can boot into systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Someone much smarter than me found the solution. I just ran these commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install systemd-sysv ubuntu-standard
```

Comment: How would you do that if you can't boot?!